# Circular import error when builiding executable with Nuitka

Tags: python, nuitka

I made a Python project using Linux and i need to generate an executable, and for that i'm using Nuitka. I want the executable to start at login.py because its the first screen viewed by the user.

My directory structure can be found below. The vast majority of the python files uses a .glade file to get their respectives GUIs. I'm also using MongoDB as a database to store user info.

````
main_folder/
├── scripts
│   ├── login.py
│   └── other python files
├── glade_screens/
│   ├── login.glade
│   └── other glade files
├── others/
│   ├── images
│   ├── sounds
│   └── ```
````

I made a python script to generate the executable that can be found below:

```py
import os
import shutil


def build_executable():
    build_dir = "dist"
    if os.path.exists(build_dir):
        shutil.rmtree(build_dir)

    os.system(
        f"python3 -m nuitka --standalone --output-dir={build_dir} scripts/login.py"
    )

    shutil.copytree("glade_screens", os.path.join(build_dir, "glade_screens"))
    shutil.copytree("others", os.path.join(build_dir, "others"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    build_executable()
```

It generates a .bin file, but when i run through the terminal i get this message:

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'MongoClient' from partially initialized module 'pymongo' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/ewro/Desktop/main_folder/dist/login.dist/pymongo/__init__.py)
```

In "login.py", i import pymongo using the line

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
```

There is no files called "pymongo" in the project, and there is no circular imports in the project. It works fine when i execute from VSCode